# Proof that $\Bbb{Q}$ ⊆ set of algebraic numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

A number is called algebraic if it is the root of a polynomial $p(x) = a_nx^
n+ a_{n−1}x^{n−1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$, where each $a_i \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Let $\Bbb{A}$ denote the set of
algebraic numbers.

(a) Prove that $\Bbb{Q} \subseteq \Bbb{A}$.

(b) Prove that the set of all algebraic numbers is countably infinite.
(Hint: First consider the possible roots of polynomials of degree k.
Then use a union argument).)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SIsP.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help, but please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: You can't find an integer polynomial satisfied by a/b?  What is your difficulty?

Comment: There’s no need to downvote so much, what difference does it make if she uses a more math.stackexchange friendly syntax? The question will remain the same at the end of the day, it’s only a difference in you’re consciousness

Comment: (a) If $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, then there are $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $r=p/q$. Therefore, $r$ is a roots of the polynomial $qx-p$.

Comment: (b) Following the argument, the number of polynomials of degree $k$ is countable, each has $k$ roots. Therefore, the number of roots coming from them is countable. Taking union for each degree it is a countable union of countable sets of roots.

Answer (score 2):

$\forall q\in\mathbb{Q}$, we can write $q=\frac{a}{b}$ in reduced form where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

We consider the simple linear equation $bz-a=0$.

Note that $p(z)=bz-a$ is a polynomial, its coefficients are in the integers, and its root is clearly $q=\frac{a}{b}$.

Since $q\in\Bbb Q$ was chosen arbitrarily, and an integer coefficient polynomial was constructed such that $q$ was a zero, then $q$ is an algebraic number. Thus $\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb A$.

$\blacksquare$